# Network Question

Tags: network-protocols

can someone explain to the problem of hidden station problem and exposed station problem and how to solve them using MACA and MACAW??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For homework problems you should use [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem)